# Best translation of おトク

Tags: translation, copywriting

So this is my first time ever making a post on a forum, so sorry if I break any rules or this has been posted somewhere else, but as the title says, I'm looking for some natural ways to say おトク・お得.

I see this word all the time and I get that it means it's cheaper or more beneficial, but in phrases like "ネットならおトク！”, I can't think of a natural way native speakers would say this in, say, an pizza ad or something.

If any of you know a good way to say this, I would really appreciate it!

Thanks.

Comment: "low price", "bargain", "at a bargain price", "special price", "bonus", whatever copy you devise, it doesn't have much to do with Japanese, the question seems more suitable for an English SE...

Comment: "Good deal", "Best price", "Great value" etc. etc. Try watching any English language shopping channel for similar words (on repeat 24 hours a day).

Comment: "a natural way native speakers would say this..." >> You mean native **English** speakers? So this is a question about English Language, not Japanese language, right?

Answer (score 2):

得（トク）means getting or earning something. If something is a お得, the price is cheaper than it should be so that you can get/earn more value from it.

You can just consider it as a noun, which means "bargain" or "on sale" and usually used in promotions and advertisements, telling people it is cheap and worth buying.

How Japanese use this word? The common cases are commercial printings and advertisements. In speaking Japanese, you can just say お得ですよ, using it as a noun, or お得なプライス(low price that you get more from it), using it as an adjective.

Answer (score 1):

yeah as it already mentioned in previous answer, お得 means the price is cheaper than usual one. So it could like, good deal, discounted plan thing like that.